# gen_server:call with new State

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp, gen-server

A module calls a `gen_server` to handle a stream, which uses record as State.

`handle_call` handles stream using a function from `State`, which separates completed piece of data and tail,

Now next time, the tail should be fed first but with an updated `State`, before the module sends in more data.

```
handle_call({stream, Data}, _From, State = #mystate{myfun=Fun}) ->
    case Fun(Data) of
       {completed piece,tail} -> 
           dosomethingwithpieace,
           NewState = State##mystate{myfun=resetfun()};
           % How do i call this again to feed Tail first with new state?
       {stillstreaming, Currentstate} ->
           NewState = State##mystate{myfun=CurrentState};
```

I cannot call `gen_server:call(self(),{stream, Tail})` because `State` needs to be updated first.
And I cannot reply with a new `State`, because module will send in more data and tail will disappear.

Is there a way to call it again with updated `State` without replying with tail and feeding tail back from module??

**Update,Code:**

```
% caller module
case gen_tcp:recv(Socket, 0) of % cannot set Length as it will block untill it is done reading Length number of bytes 
    {ok, Data} ->
        Response = gen_server:call(Pid, {handle_init,Socket,Data}),
        case Response of
            {ok, continue} ->
                pre_loop(Socket, Pid);
            {ok, logged_in} ->
                {UserId, UserName} = get_user_data(), % ignore it for now.
                receiver_loop(UserId, UserName, Socket, Pid);
            {stop, Reason} ->
                io:format("Error at pre_loop: ~p~n", [Reason]);
            _ ->
                io:format("Unknown response from call in pre-loop: ~p~n", [Response])
        end;
    {error, closed} -> % done here as no data was stored in mnesia yet.
        gen_server:stop(Pid),
        io:format("Client died in pre_loop~n")
end.
```

and gen_server module:

```
% gen_server module
handle_call({handle_init, _Socket, Data}, _From, State = #server_state{data_fun =  {incomplete, Fun}}) ->
    case catch Fun(Data) of
        {incomplete, F} ->
            NewState = State#server_state{data_fun = {incomplete, F}},
            {reply, {ok, continue}, NewState};
        {with_tail, Term, Tail} ->
            % handle Term login/register only
            case handle_input_init(Term, Tail) of
                {incomplete, Fn, logged_in} ->
                    NewState = State#server_state{data_fun = {incomplete, Fn}},
                    {reply, {ok, logged_in}, NewState};
                {incomplete, Fn} ->
                    NewState = State#server_state{data_fun = {incomplete, Fn}},
                    {reply, {ok, continue}, NewState};
                {stop, malformed_data} ->
                    {reply, {stop, malformed_data}, State}
            end;
        _ ->
            {reply, {stop, malformed_data}, State}
    end;

handle_call(_Message, _From, State = #server_state{}) ->
{reply, {stop , unknown_call}, State}.

handle_input_init(Term, Tail) ->
case handle_term_init(Term) of
    {ok, login_passed} ->
        io:format("send user a login pass msg"),
        handle_tail_init(Tail, logged_in);
    {error, login_failed} ->
        io:format("send user a login failed error~n"),
        handle_tail_init(Tail);
    {ok, registration_passed} ->
        io:format("send user a registeration passed msg"),
        handle_tail_init(Tail);
    {error, registration_failed} ->
        io:format("send user a registeration failed error"),
        handle_tail_init(Tail);
    {error, invalidreq} ->
        io:format("send user an invalid requst error~n"),
        handle_tail_init(Tail)
end.

handle_tail_init(Tail) ->
case catch jsx:decode(Tail, [stream, return_tail, return_maps]) of
    {incomplete, F} ->
        {incomplete, F};
    {with_tail, Term, Tail2} ->
        handle_input_init(Term, Tail2);
    _ ->
        {stop, malformed_data}
end.

handle_tail_init(Tail, logged_in) -> % because it was logged in already, any further requests should be ignored
case catch jsx:decode(Tail, [stream, return_tail, return_maps]) of
    {incomplete, F} ->
        {incomplete, F, logged_in};
    {with_tail, _Term, Tail2} ->
        io:format("send user an invalid requst error~n"),
        handle_tail_init(Tail2, logged_in);
    _ ->
        {stop, malformed_data}
end.

handle_term_init(Term) ->
case Term of
    #{<<"Login">> := [UserName,Password]} ->
        login_user(UserName,Password);
    #{<<"Register">> := [UserName,Password]} ->
        register_user(UserName,Password);
    _ ->
        {error, invalidreq}
end.
```

It is working as expected but this is my very first Erlang code ever and i am positive that it can be simplified to a single *recursive* `handle_call`, maintaining OTP style, the reason I chose Erlang.

Comment: Never use pronouns when writing anything--who knows what `it` and `this` refer to.  Well, you know--but you are the only one.  You can save anything you want in State: expand it to a 1,000 element tuple if needed where one element is your record, then you can use the other 999 slots to store pieces of anything you want--including your disappearing tail.  Also, I don't think your question has anything to do with streams, so create a simple example that demonstrates your problem without using streams, e.g. `handle_call({go, Data}, _From, Func) -> case Func(Data) of {X, Y}`

Comment: Its not my tail xD and yes i know i can but this does not solve the problem, i can use thousands of tuples or write multiple function to solve it but it will create many more problems i.e. what if the tail contains a complete piece of data or is a complete piece itself? i will have to handle completed pieces everywhere in addition to writing complex code.

Answer (score 3):

> I cannot call gen_server:call(self(),{stream, Tail}) because State
>   needs to be updated first.

I can't really understand what you are trying to say, but if you mean:

> I cannot ***recursively*** call `gen_server:call(self(),{stream, Tail})`, i.e. I cannot write code in `handle:call()` that recursively calls `handle_call()`.

then you can certainly send all the data inside `handle:call()` to another function that recursively calls itself:

```
handle_call(...) ->

    ...
    NewState = ....
    Result = ...
    {FinalResult, FinalState} = helper_func(Result, NewState, Tail)
    {reply, FinalResult, FinalState}

helper_func(Result, State, []) ->
    {Result, State};
helper_func(Result, State, [Piece|Tail]) ->
    ...
    NewState = ...
    NewResult = ...
    helper_func(NewResult, NewState, Tail).  %% Recursive call here
```

Comment: caller needs to know the result of each call to decide if it should proceed or not, i tried with handle_continue which can help me call handle_call recursively with updated State but it also does update State in reply, also there is reply(From,Reply) but caller will handle one reply only if i am not wrong.

Comment: issue here is not how to make it work, issue is how to make it work the way it should (otp style). if nothing works i will be limiting read buffer to make sure tail does not ever contain a completed piece and just go with handle_continue(tail, Tail)

Comment: ***caller needs to know the result of each call to decide if it should proceed or not,***--That's the only thing that you've written that clearly states what you are trying to do. ***issue here is not how to make it work, issue is how to make it work the way it should***-- Unfortunately, you don't have the writing skills to communicate how *it should work*.  I gather that there is some data that you want to persist between calls to `gen_server:call()`, but that is exactly what the LoopData for a gen_server does.

Comment: Caller sends in data, handle_call separates chunks and any extra data which is left over is return = tail, does what ever needs to be done with that chunk and replies with the result, now tail might also contains useful chunks so before replying, tail also needs to be handled which cannot be done as handle_call cannot be called recursively and caller will only handle one reply. Tail might contain more than 1 useful chunks and without them, input data will get broken because of missing data (which is tail) hence needs to be handled strictly

Comment: I am currently only replying continue or stop signals to the caller and processing everything in gen_server, which also will be a problem as i proceed further with my project.

Comment: @user10844401, ***any extra data which is left over is return = tail*** -- What does `return = tail` mean??????????????  ***does what ever needs to be done with that chunk*** --  Huh?

Comment: Function returns completed piece and tail, return = tail means return value of the function, do you want me to explain what i do with the data? Is result after processing completed piece is returned to the caller as reply is not enough?